# Why do we declare the unsubscribe method for an event emitter in its subscribe method declaration?

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend

I read this implementation of an event emitter on LeetCode and wanted to ask a few questions.

1. What purpose does it serve to have the `release` method in the return of the `subscribe` method? Why can't I make it its own method?
2. How do I use the `unsubscribe` method like this and how would I use it if it was its own method?
3. The author said the reason behind putting the callback inside an object was to be able to add multiple callbacks of the same name. Is that considered good practice?
4. Any recommendations as to how to make this implementation better (readability, structure)?
5. Why isn't `subscriptions` variable defined in a `constructor`?

Thank you.

```
class EventEmitter {
  subscriptions = new Map()
  
  subscribe(eventName, callback) {
    if (!this.subscriptions.has(eventName)) {
      this.subscriptions.set(eventName, new Set())
    }
    const newSub = { callback }
    this.subscriptions.get(eventName).add(newSub)
    
    return {
      unsubscribe: () => {
        const evSub = this.subscriptions.get(eventName)
        evSub.delete(newSub)
        if (evSub.size === 0)
          this.subscriptions.delete(eventName)
      }
    }
  }
  
  emit(eventName, ...args) {
    const callbacks = this.subscriptions.get(eventName)
    if (!callbacks) return
    
    for (let c of callbacks) {
      c.callback(...args)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For 1 and 2, at least, it's probably just so the unsubscribe method can capture the event name variable. A separate method could work but it would require a bind() first to send the event name along. Either way, you create a new function object each time.

Comment: Try answering question 2 for yourself. The answer to question 1 should become obvious then.

Comment: For question 3: yes. For question 4: that's off-topic on StackOverflow, try [codereview.SE] instead. It works better for your own code though not someone else's.

Comment: I got another question --sorry-- why isn't `subscriptions` is declared inside a `constructor`?

Comment: The explanation for 3 seems a little off, in particular the thing about adding callbacks with the same *name*. The callback passed in doesn't necessarily have a name. A more sensible explanation is that wrapping it in an object makes it possible to add the same callback multiple times, since a `Set` discards duplicates.

Comment: @Lennholm yes, it shouldn't be "with the same name" but "with the same identity"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. What purpose does it serve to have the release method in the return of the subscribe method? Why can't I make it its own method?

**Answer 1:** In case unsubscribing needs information only available from making the subscription (like a subscription `eventName`) it makes sense to provide the function directly from the creation. It saves you having to store data needed in the unsubscription process in some intermediary form. You can make it is own method if you want, but still need to return it as in this code:

```js
unsubscribe(eventName) => {
  const evSub = this.subscriptions.get(eventName)
  evSub.delete(newSub)
  if (evSub.size === 0)
    this.subscriptions.delete(eventName)
}

subscribe(eventName, callback) {
  if (!this.subscriptions.has(eventName)) {
    this.subscriptions.set(eventName, new Set())
  }
  const newSub = { callback }
  this.subscriptions.get(eventName).add(newSub)
    
  return () => unsubscribe(eventName);
}
```

2. How do I use the unsubscribe method like this and how would I use it if it was its own method?

**Answer 2:** You store the return value from `subscribe` some place you can access it, then invoke it if needed by calling `unsubscribe()`. How it's used is not different whether it's in its own function or not. It still needs to know the `eventName` so you need the one returned from `subscribe`. Like in this code:

```js
const unsub = subscribe("event1", () => {});
// then later 
unsub();  // unsubscribe from event1
```

3. The author said the reason behind putting the callback inside an object was to be able to add multiple callbacks of the same name. Is that considered good practice?

**Answer 3:** There's nothing wrong with it. It's a design choice.

4. Any recommendations as to how to make this implementation better (readability, structure)?

**Answer 4:** That's personal choice.

5. Why isn't subscription defined in a constructor?

**Answer 5:** I assume you're asking about `subscriptions` variable (plural) and not the `subscription` function. It's defined as a class variable which doesn't need any initialization specific to a ctor parameter so there's no need to make one. You could put it in a ctor if you wanted to but it just makes the code longer without any real benefit. If the ctor took in some parameters that would affect the initial value of `subscriptions` then it could be done in the ctor.

Comment: 1. "needs information only available from making the subscription" doesn't `eventName` is already given as a param to the `unsubscribe` method? The only one not given is the `callback`. However, can't I declare it as a param too?
5. Can you elaborate? What's ctor? and when do I use a `constructor`?

Comment: You forgot to pass `newSub` to `unsubscribe`

Comment: Also notice that the original code doesn't return a function from `subscribe()`, but rather a subscription object with an `.unsubscribe()` method

Comment: Nice answer, It really helped me!